# Magento 2 Full Page Cache issue while adding product to the cart in custom theme

Tags: magento2

I created the custom theme in magento 2 and am using custom REST API for adding the product to the cart. It works well when i disabled the FPC, but while enabling FPC, the added products in the cart disappers when the page is refreshed.
It seems to be creating fresh quote id whenever am refreshing the page after adding the product.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As per my understanding this issue has no relation with FPC. you need to troubleshoot  if you have done any customization around the checkout or quote.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
 Actually when am disabling FPC, the checkout flow works well.
You are right i need to customize my custom REST API's, but am not able to find the accurate solution for this issue.
Any hint will be help ful to me.